# How to find anti-derivative of $f(x):=\sin(x)\cos(nx)$.

Tags: integration

> How to find anti-derivative of $f(x):=\sin(x)\cos(nx)$.

I know the sum-formulas for $\sin(x),\cos(x)$ which I could put to use if $x = nx$, but this is not the case here where $n \in \mathbb N$.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Hint: The sum and product formulas, $\sin c+ \sin d=2sin((c+d)/2)cos((c-d)/2)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Use $2 \cos x \sin y = \sin(x + y) - \sin(x - y)$.

Comment: Thank you ! This was just what I needed.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen You're welcome.